# Sintaxis de esta consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esta consulta

```
$CeanLibre = "SELECT min(`3`) + 1 as prox_ean_libre FROM (SELECT 0 AS `3` union all SELECT `3` FROM `Direcciones&Codigos` WHERE `3` BETWEEN 
'".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[4]."' AND 
'".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[5]."' ) `t1` WHERE not exists (select null 
FROM `Direcciones&Codigos` t2 WHERE `t2.3` = `t1.3` + 1 AND `t2.3` BETWEEN 
'".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[4]."' AND 
".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[5]."' )"; //miramos de nuevo el ultimo codigo por si aca

    $REanLibre = mysqli_query($Conectar ,$CeanLibre); //pongo un resultado de la consulta

    $DEanLibre=mysqli_fetch_array($REanLibre); 

    $EanLibre = trim($DEanLibre["prox_ean_libre"]);
```

Pero me da un error.

> ```
> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '' )' at line 1
>
> <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
> ```

creo que es por alguna `` ` `` y no se si la sintaxis sería esa. `"3"` es el nombre de una columna de mysql

Tengo también esta que es similar y no da fallo:

```
$CIdmaxFactS = "SELECT MAX(CAST(`3` AS UNSIGNED)) AS ultimoean FROM `Direcciones&Codigos` WHERE `3` BETWEEN '".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[4]."' AND '".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[5]."' ";
    $RIdmaxFactS = mysqli_query($Conectar ,$CIdmaxFactS);
    $DIdmaxFactS=mysqli_fetch_array($RIdmaxFactS); 
    $idmaxFactS = trim($DIdmaxFactS["ultimoean"]);
```

Lo unico que en esta segunda busca el ultimo numero y yo necesito que me mire el primero que este libre.

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano? a ver si veis algo que se me escapa.

Comment: Por el Warning que te da parece ser que la consulta no esta funcionando. Deberías revisar que devuelve la consulta. Más no te puedo decir con esa porción de código.

Comment: puedes publicar tu error completo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta una comilla simple (') en la última línea de la consulta. Te dejo la query resuelta. Espero que te ayude.

```
$CeanLibre = "SELECT min(`3`) + 1 as prox_ean_libre 
                FROM (
                     SELECT 0 AS `3` 
                      union all 
                            SELECT `3` 
                              FROM `Direcciones&Codigos` 
                              WHERE `3` BETWEEN  '".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[4]."' AND  '".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[5]."' 
                     ) `t1` 
               WHERE not exists (
                     select null  
                       FROM `Direcciones&Codigos` t2 
                      WHERE `t2.3` = `t1.3` + 1 
                        AND `t2.3` BETWEEN '".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[4]."' 
                                       AND '".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[5]."'
               --                         ^^^ 
                                )";
```

Comment: Si, era eso :) Mil gracias

Comment: El caso es que el resultado siempre me da 1 :_( debe de haber algo mal